# Is there a way to search for a particular type of resource?

Tags: glitch-2011

I often need to track down a specific type of tree, rock, animal, etc. However, the zone map doesn't seem to give any indication of what resources are where. I have to either rely on my limited memory, or just wander in hopes of finding what I'm looking for.

Is there any way in-game, on the site, that I can search for a particular resource and get a map of where it can be found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty good site called [Zog's Glitchy Tools](http://zoggish.appspot.com/locations). You can click any resource, log-in, and it will give you the closest location of that resource to your current location.

Comment: Nice. Not quite as convenient as a map, but still a very good resource.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite resource site is the [Glitch Resource Database](http://glitch.alwaysdata.net/).  It's quick and doesn't require a login.